# Custom audio file doesn't play for UNUserNotificationCenter on mac

Tags: swift, cocoa, audio, swiftui, nsnotificationcenter

I'm building a menu bar app on BigSur. The application sends `UserNotifications` ever so often. I want to apply a different sound to the `.default` sound User notifications are shown. I am having a little trouble getting the sound to play. I've done everything I can, and yet cannot get it to work.

What I've done so far (The audio file is `one.caf`)

1. Check if the audio file is in the `Copy Bundle resources`, and it is there

[image]

2. Check with multiple audio formats (`.mp3, .wav, .caf`)
3. Change locations from `project root` to the `controllers` directory

[image]

4. Cleaned the build folder, cleared derived data followed by a reboot
5. Get the path using `Bundle.main.url()` and then calling `.lastPathComponent`

[image]

6. I've checked if the target has been selected for the file

[image]

7. I've checked if the file is in the same directory in `finder` as well.

[image]

I'm not sure if it has something to do with how I'm invoking the notifications, but I doubt it. Either way, here is the code I run when I need to show a notification. FYI, I'm using a `singleton` class for managing notifications

```
    private func showNotification(title: String, subtitle: String) {
        let content = UNMutableNotificationContent()
        content.title = title
        content.subtitle = subtitle
   
        // Getting asset name using URL
        let stringPath = Bundle.main.url(forResource: "one", withExtension: "caf")
        print(stringPath?.lastPathComponent)


//        content.sound = UNNotificationSound(named: UNNotificationSoundName(rawValue: "one.caf"))
        UNNotificationSound(named: UNNotificationSoundName(stringPath?.lastPathComponent ?? ""))
        content.sound = .defaultCritical
        let request = UNNotificationRequest(identifier: UUID().uuidString, content: content, trigger: nil)
        UNUserNotificationCenter.current().add(request)
    }
```

The the contents of the package are
[image]

Comment: Make sure that the target checkbox is turned on for the audio file.

Comment: I checked that as well, still doesn’t work :(

Comment: If you open the package, where do you find your audio file?

Comment: It is in side the rood directory. I have edited the answer, please check the points 6 & 7

Comment: I don't care as to where your audio file is locally located in your hard drive.  Right-click on the app package to see where the file is actually placed.

Comment: Just to clarify, by app package you mean the blue `.xcproj` file correct?

Comment: Select your app file (.app) inside the sidebar to the left.  Then choose Show in Finder.

Comment: I've editted the answer with screenshots of the package location

Comment: This is your last chance.  1. Locate your application file (Pinpoint.app).  2. Right-click on the application file and open the package.  3. Locate your audio and find out exactly where in the Resources folder it's located.

Comment: It's in the /Resources directory, check the screenshot

Comment: Move your application file to the Applications folder.  That's the only possibility left for wrongdoing.

Comment: I did, it doesn't work :(. Any idea what could be causing this? Do i need to set up the project for APN's?

Comment: @VisalRajapakse Check if you can play system sound. Make sure your caf is correct as per https://developer.apple.com/documentation/usernotifications/unnotificationsound In your code your sound isn't set/attached to notification